# determine if b is a linear combination of the vectors formed from columns of A

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry if this has been covered in another thread but i wanted an answer tailored to my situation. My guess is that you would set up an augmented matrix and row reduce to see if the system is consistent or not. Consistency would indicate yes b can and non consistency would indicate no b cant. However given the matrix A: 
$\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 5 \\ -2 & 1 & -6 \\ 0 & 2 & 8}$
and the column vector b:
$\pmatrix{2 \\ -1 \\ 6}$

giving an augmented matrix of:
$\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 5 & 2 \\ -2 & 1 & -6 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 8 & 6}$

after row reduction I got:
$\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 5 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0}$

This of course indicates that the system is consistent and in fact has infinitely many solutions but does this mean that this particular vector can written as a linear combination? I believe this indicates yes, but is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The range of a linear transformation represented by matrix $A$ is the span of its columns. This is due to the view of matrix multiplication as taking linear combinations of matrix columns. Determining whether $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ is equivalent to determining whether $b$ is in the range of the linear transformation represented by $A$, i.e. whether the system $Ax=b$ is consistent.

You have done the requisite work to show that this system is consistent (you have shown the augmented matrix and $A$ have the same rank), and therefore, yes, $b$ is a linear combination of the columns. Make sure to understand why (above paragraph).